# How can I use the same function for three different variables?

Tags: javascript

How can I use the same function for three different variables?

```
var game = {score:0},

scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score1");

function add20() {
  TweenLite.to(game, 1, {score:"+=20", roundProps:"score", onUpdate:updateHandler, ease:Linear.easeNone});
}

function updateHandler() {
  scoreDisplay.innerHTML = game.score;
}

add20();
```

I've tried breaking it down to three separate functions `function add20()`, `function add40()` and `function add60()` but I know this isn't following the DRY approach. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: call the function add which takes in an argument score. then do {score:score}

Answer (score 7):

Pass as parameter:

```
function add(n) {
  TweenLite.to(game, 1, {score:"+=" + n, roundProps:"score", onUpdate:updateHandler, ease:Linear.easeNone});
}
add(20);
add(40);
add(60);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass arguments to function making it more dynamic:

```
function addScore(score) {
    TweenLite.to(game, 1, {score:"+="+score, roundProps:"score", onUpdate:updateHandler, ease:Linear.easeNone});
}

addScore(20);
addScore(40);
addScore(60);
```

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make it super clear, but there are also three different IDs: scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score1");                  scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score2");                  scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score3");                                  Thanks ))

Comment: I've created a fiddle to illustrate the issue. I'm trying to get the black numbers to count as well: https://jsfiddle.net/jnoweb/xrpsshcp/